# Select2 How to control srollbar in select2-4.0.2 version for too long data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-select2

I have one question need your help about how to control srollbar in select2-4.0.2 version for too long data .

My requirement is : when option tags exceed  5 option  , i need display vertical scrollbar for dropdown windows similar to size attribute under select tag ( )   , For this requirement  how set option in select2 ?

for example :

```
<option value="AL">Alabama</option>
<option value="AK">Alaska</option>
<option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
<option value="AR">Arkansas</option>
<option value="CA">California</option>
<option value="CO">Colorado</option>
<option value="CT">Connecticut</option>
<option value="DE">Delaware</option>
<option value="FL">Florida</option>
<option value="GA">Georgia</option>
<option value="HI">Hawaii</option>
<option value="ID">Idaho</option>
</select>

<script>
$('.select2').css('width','200px').select2({allowClear:true})
</script>
```

BR
Kai

Comment: https://github.com/select2/select2/issues/2762